# Maven - Export Classpath based on dependencies without .m2 overhead

Tags: maven, classpath

The pom-code at the bottom below creates a classpath file containing all jar files relative to the .m2 maven cache:

```
${M2_REPO}\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;${M2_REPO}\com\github\jnr\jnr-ffi\2.1.7\jnr-ffi-2.1.7.jar;...
```

Al dependencies are neatly copied to target/lib

```
${project.build.directory}/lib
```

I wonder how I can get maven to create the classpath using the path of my target/lib directory rather than the maven cache:

```
target/libslf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:target/lib/jnr-ffi-2.1.7.jar:...
```

Iam using the following maven code:

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
          <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
          <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
          <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>build-classpath</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>build-classpath</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <attach>true</attach>
          <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/classpath</outputFile>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: What is the advantage if you use target?

Comment: I would like to have a configuration which builds my project and arranges all dependencies in one target directory. Currently thats target/myproject.jar and target/lib. That part is working. What I miss is a way to have a classpath or a manifest which includes all my dependencies in target/lib and in correct order. build-path gives me the correct order of jars but it refers to the .m2-Maven directory. For now I have to manually edit the classpath and update my start scripts each time the dependencies change.

Comment: Thank you, I understood what you want, but I would like to know _why_ you want this. What problem do you want to solve by building a classpath with entries in target (which cannot be solved with the  "usual" classpath)?

Comment: What kind of project you are building? WAR/EAR ?

Answer (score 0):

The following does the job for me:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}${file.separator}lib</outputDirectory>
          <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
          <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
          <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>build-classpath</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>build-classpath</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <attach>true</attach>
          <outputFile>${project.build.directory}${file.separator}classpath</outputFile>
          <prefix>target${file.separator}lib</prefix>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```